# How do I alternate between two color animations infinitely?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm a bit of a newbie to CSS3 animations, but I've looked everywhere, and I can't find a solution to this problem. I have a JSP page that I want the background to slowly fade from green to blue, and then slowly fade the opposite way and repeat this process infinitely.

I currently have it go from green to blue smoothly, but then it jerks back to blue instantly. Is there a way to play two animations from green to blue, then blue to green and repeat infinitely?

Here's the CSS code I have now:

```
@keyframes changeColorGreenToBlue {
    from { background-color: rgb(146,213,142);}
    to {background-color: rgb(133,184,222);}
}
@keyframes changeColorBlueToGreen {
    from {background-color: rgb(133,184,222);}
    to { background-color: rgb(146,213,142);}
}
.jumbotron {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    animation: changeColorGreenToBlue ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: changeColorBlueToGreen;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

It's a little messy because I was just trying everything to get it working. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than two keyframe animations, you want one that changes the background color twice (once at 50%, and back at 100%), like this:

```
@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(146,213,142);
  }

  50% {
    background-color: rgb(133,184,222);
  }

  100% {
    background-color: rgb(146,213,142);
  }
}
```

See [my codepen](http://codepen.io/kalendubrick/pen/pyLoaL) for example in action.

Comment: BTW you don't need `animation-fill-mode` here.

Comment: @TylerH I was just copying Tim's animation code verbatim as a quick and dirty solution, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice. Just thought you wrote it all!